# C# Reflection Lists: Object does not match target type

Tags: c#, reflection

Trying to add a class object into a List using reflection, but when invoking the Add method with my class object as a parameter, I get 'Object does not match target type'

Here's the snippet code in concern (you can assume `classString = "Processor"` for now)

```
PC fetched = new PC();

// Get the appropriate computer field to write to
FieldInfo field = fetched.GetType().GetField(classString);

// Prepare a container by making a new instance of the reffered class
// "CoreView" is the namespace of the program.
object classContainer = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("CoreView." + classString));

/*
    classContainer population code
*/

// This is where I get the error. I know that classContainer is definitely
// the correct type for the list it's being added to at this point.
field.FieldType.GetMethod("Add").Invoke(fetched, new[] {classContainer});
```

Then this is part of the class the above code is adding classContainers to:

```
public class PC
{
    public List<Processor> Processor = new List<Processor>();
    public List<Motherboard> Motherboard = new List<Motherboard>();
    // Etc...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to call `List.Add(Processor)` on `PC` - you want to call it on the *value of the field*:

```
field.FieldType.GetMethod("Add").Invoke(field.GetValue(fetched),
                                        new[] {classContainer});
```

However, I'd personally advise you *not* to have public fields like this. Consider using properties instead.

Comment: That did the trick! It's amazing how every single time I expose a public field, someone complains =P. Don't worry, they will become properties once I'm closer to release of the program. I still don't wholly understand why they should be properties though.

Comment: @CJxD: See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx for some arguments. You may not even want to expose them directly as lists - you may want to just expose certain operations, such as `AddProcessor`, `AddMotherboard` etc. It depends what level of encapsulation you want to achieve.

Comment: Get hold of a code analysis tool and turn it on your code. It will howl in anguish. From members with the same names as types, not using properties, exposing concrete types... You aren't doing yourself anyfavours with this sort of shortcut. public List<Processor> Processors {get; set;} (or better yet private set), is hardly some huge an unconscionable burden.

Answer (score 0):

This method will add new item to all list//just instead of insert use Add

```
        IList list = (IList)value;// this what you need to do convert ur parameter value to ilist

        if (value == null)
        {
            return;//or throw an excpetion
        }

        Type magicType = value.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];//Get class type of list
        ConstructorInfo magicConstructor = magicType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);//Get constructor reference

        if (magicConstructor == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Object {0} does not have a default constructor defined", magicType.Name.ToString()));
        }

        object magicClassObject = magicConstructor.Invoke(new object[] { });//Create new instance
        if (magicClassObject == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(string.Format("Class {0} cannot be null.", magicType.Name.ToString()));
        }
        list.Insert(0, magicClassObject);
        list.Add(magicClassObject);
```